# Browse Bash files for a distribution

Tags: linux, bash, source

With my current OS, my `LANG` value is set by

```
/etc/profile.d/lang.sh
```

I am curious of the code for another distribution, Linux Mint for example. How could I browse this code online, or perhaps download the code without actually installing that OS? I would prefer not to download an ISO if possible.

Comment: In principle, you could do it; in practice the only way to do so is to follow @signal11's lead in the answer: Have people tell you.

Answer (score 1):

On my system ( `cat /etc/redhat-release` => 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 6)
`LANG` is also set in this file eg here is section of `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh`

```
sourced=0
for langfile in /etc/sysconfig/i18n $HOME/.i18n ; do
    [ -f $langfile ] && . $langfile && sourced=1
done

if [ -n "$GDM_LANG" ]; then
    sourced=1
    LANG="$GDM_LANG"
    unset LANGUAGE
    if [ "$GDM_LANG" = "zh_CN.GB18030" ]; then
      export LANGUAGE="zh_CN.GB18030:zh_CN.GB2312:zh_CN"
    fi
fi
```